# AngularJs's $watch function - without return ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

According to the documentation of $[watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch) :

> The `watchExpression` is called on every call to `$digest()` and **should
>   return the value that will be watched**.

If so , how come this code works ? ([**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/EpUvegag/2/edit))

```
 $scope.$watch(function() {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        total = total + $scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].quantity;
      }
      $scope.bill.total = total;
      $scope.bill.discount = total > 100 ? 10 : 0;
      $scope.bill.subtotal = total - $scope.bill.discount;
    });
```

I don't see any `return`  here.

And the docs say explicitly that a return value to watch - should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer in response to the question: "If $scope.$watch watches nothing (undefined) , how come it runs ?"

Here are some posts about how the digest cycle and watchers work in Angular:

```
* http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html
* http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/
```

It is important to remember that Angular will always run each `watchExpression` *at least once* during each digest cycle. But it will only run the `listener` function if the value of the `watchExpression` is different to the previous invocation.

Here is a simple example where you want `scope.otherCount` to be set to the same value as `scope.count`.

```
$scope.count = 1;
$scope.otherCount = 0;

$scope.$watch(function(){
    // This function is called multiple times every digest cycle.
    // We should return a value to let Angular know when the listener needs to be run.

    // If the return value of this function is different between two calls then the listener will run.

    console.log('watchExpression');

    // This is important for Angular to know that our watch value has changed.
    return $scope.count;

}, function(newValue){

    // When the value of `$scope.count` changes this listener will be run to update `$scope.otherCount`.

    // The reason this listner is called is because our `watchExpression` above will
    // have returned a different value.
    $scope.otherCount = $scope.count;

    console.log('count=', $scope.count);
    console.log('count=', $scope.otherCount);
});
```

Compare that to your watch and you should see what is going on.

---

### Original Answer:

There are a few hidden questions that I've tried to address with my response:

### 1 - "Why is this not an error?"

Your example is valid JavaScript - the return value of a function that does not explicitly return a value is `undefined`.

```
function a(){
    // Don't return anything.
}

a() === undefined;  // true
```

Angular runs your `watchExpression` function and receives the value `undefined` from it each time. As far as Angular is concerned, the value of your `watchExpression` never changes.

### 2 - "Why does it work?"

You are updating the `$scope` every time the `watchExpression` is run so you will see the correct values in the view.

However, Angular runs the `watchExpression` multiple times in every digest cycle meaning that the `$scope` is being updated more often than it should.

### 3 - "How should it be changed?"

If you are using **Angular 1.2** (or later) then you should use the new `$scope.$watchCollection` method to watch the values inside the array:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function(){
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        total = total + $scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].quantity;
    }
    $scope.bill.total = total;
    $scope.bill.discount = total > 100 ? 10 : 0;
    $scope.bill.subtotal = total - $scope.bill.discount;
});
```

This will watch the `$scope.items` array and run the listener function any time the array or the items in the array changes.

---

If you are using an earlier version of angular (e.g. **Angular 1.0.x**) then you will need to find a different way of triggering the recalculation:

**HTML:**

Add an `ng-change` event to the input fields and recalculate whenever their values change:

```
...
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    <!-- Add ng-change="itemChanged()" to the input -->
    <input ng-model="item.quantity" ng-change="itemChanged()" />
    <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
    <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
</div>
...
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Define a single function that is responsible for calculating the totals.
function calculateTotals(){
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        total = total + $scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].quantity;
    }
    $scope.bill.total = total;
    $scope.bill.discount = total > 100 ? 10 : 0;
    $scope.bill.subtotal = total - $scope.bill.discount;
}

// Add a $watch that will calculate the totals when the array length changes.
$scope.$watch('items', calculateTotals);

// Recalculate the totals when the input value changes.
$scope.itemChanged = function(){
    calculateTotals();
};
```

Comment: p.s. regarding `watchCollection('items'`... I'm currently reading abook where it says that my approach is better for large data arrays. ( since NG creates a clone of data).... again. i'm ng-beginner.

Comment: In that case you can use the second example - the `ng-change` event - to trigger the recalculation only when the user changes the input value.

Comment: Does every set to `$scope.bill.xxx=...` calls digest which in turn runs the `$watch` ?

Comment: Not necessarily - Angular will know when the values on `$scope.bill` aren't changing any more, but your code is still doing more work than it needs to inside that watcher. Your watch should be as small and quick as possible because it is run quite frequently. Add a `console.log('calculate totals')` inside your watchExpression to see how many times the watcher is running each digest.

Comment: If $scope.$watch watches nothing (undefined) , how come it runs ?

Answer (score 2):

On every `digest` the `watch` is called. `watch` is looking whether the `watchExpression` (usually a variable; the first argument of `$watch()`) has changed. In your case the first argument of `$watch()` is a function, not a variable (that's actually not a problem, but a cause of your problem :) ). So each time `digest` is called, it executes `watch` and that executes your function. That's why it works.

EDIT:
That function of yours could or should have a `return` which will return a variable, to be watched for change... anyway any code in your function, before `return` statement will be executed.

Comment: And who triggers the digest ? this line `$scope.bill.total = total;` ?

Comment: I mean can you write the cycle  of events ?